# Question regarding singleton scope and instance variables

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, inversion-of-control, javabeans

I'm new to Java programming and the Spring framework. It is my understanding that Java bean classes with instance variables are stateful, hence they are not thread-safe and should **not** be singletons. This is why I have marked all my Java bean classes that have instance variables using the following annotation

```
Scope("prototype")
```

However, I came across a piece of code from an open-source project that looks like the following (some parts are redacted):

```
@Path("/clients")
@Component
@Scope("singleton")
public class ClientsApiResource
{
  private final PlatformSecurityContext context;

  @Autowired
  public ClientsApiResource( final PlatformSecurityContext context )
  {
    this.context = context;
  }

  private void verifyPermission() throws PermissionViolationException
  {
    AppUser user = this.context.authenticatedUser();
    if( !user.hasPermission( "VIEW_CLIENT_PROFILE" ) )
    {
      throw new PermissionViolationException( "User does not have required permission to view client profile!" );
    }
  }
}
```

I'm confused by this piece of code.

1. `ClientsApiResource` is a singleton class, which means there is only one instance of it created upon application startup.
2. A `PlatformSecurityContext` object, which contains user authentication information, is injected into the singleton `ClientsApiResource` object when the latter was created, and being a final variable the `PlatformSecurityContext` object does not change throughout the `ClientsApiResource` object's lifespan.
3. The singleton `ClientsApiResource` object serves multiple HTTP requests. My understanding is that each request is served by a different thread created by the Spring framework, but all these threads share the same `ClientsApiResource` object and the same `PlatformSecurityContext` object.

How come the same `PlatformSecurityContext` object can represent multiple users? I'm confused.

Comment: Are you sure that open source project actually works?

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. The fact that something has an instance variable doesn't mean it holds state!. A service has a reference to a repository (DAO or something alike) but that isn't state. If you have an instance variable and change that inside a method then you are keeping state.